# Retrieving Data From IndexedDB

Tags: indexeddb

I am new in IndexedDB. I need to fetch data as per my requirement.
Requirement is :-

I have one object stored in IndexedDB.

Object Format is : -

```
var _obj = {
    COL_TITLE : '1',
    COL_ID : 'proxyserver#1235',
    COL_NAME : 'proxyserver',
    COL_VERSION : ['TASK#1','TASK#2','TASK#3','TASK#4']
}
```

I want to fetch data according to `'TASK#2'`. For this i had created index `'VERSIONINDEX'` using this

```
this.store.createIndex('VERSIONINDEX', 'data.COL_VERSION', {unique:false});
```

Using this index i am fetching record. but i got empty array.
can anyone tell me how i can achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a multi-entry index.

```
// in onupgradeneeded
store.createIndex('colVersionIndex','COL_VERSION', {multiEntry:true});

// in query
store.index('colVersionIndex').openCursor('TASK#2').onsuccess = function() {
  var cursor = this.result;
  if(!cursor) return;
  console.log('got task %o', cursor.value); 
};
```